Is "none" a valid ARIA role?
SonarCloud analysis is complaining about an <li role="none"> element: "Elements with ARIA roles must use a valid, non-abstract ARIA role. "none" is not a valid role."
I can't find any information explaining why "none" would be considered invalid or abstract.
Why would "none" not be considered valid?

none is a valid value for the role attribute. It was introduced in WAI-ARIA 1.1 as a synonym for role="presentation". Both values have the same effect, namely removing an element's native semantics. (role="none" was introduced because there were misunderstandings about the meaning of `role="presentation"´.)
In a regular list, role="none" or role="presentation" would not be valid. However, if you are using list markup for a menu, <li role="none"> is very common, since the <a> elements inside <li role="none"> usually get a menuitem role.
At the time of writing, Sonar (Sonar Cloud, Sonar Lint etc) has some accessibility checks, but these are still limited and imperfect. Flagging <li role="none"> without checking whether this code is used in something like <ul role="menu"> can easily lead to false positives. This looks like something that should be reported as a false positive on Sonar Community.

It is a valid role with very-well defined semantic:

MDN
digitala11y
w3.org

I think SonarCloud analysis just wrong here, or not up to date

We could add that none is just a synonym for presentation. The addition of none is fairly recent, so sonar may not be up to date. If needed, for the purpose of just removing the false positive, you can use presentation instead of none.
